# Kotlin thread stops application after finishing

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

I'm trying to get text from my server using `URL.readText`, but when the thread finishes the application stops running. Here is my thread function.

```
fun connect() {
        val t = Thread(Runnable {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            val str = URL("https://server.necrodragon41.repl.co/server/connect").readText(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
            if (str == "connected") {
                Thread.sleep(1500)
                ConnectingText.text = "Collecting saved data..."
            } else {
                ConnectingText.text = "Error connecting."
            }
        })
        t.start()
    }
```

The thread actually finishes running before the application stops because behind the popup that says there was an error I can see the `collecting saved data...`. How can I avoid the application from stopping?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would your application _do_ after the thread stops?  And what platform/framework is this for (e.g. command line, Android, Swing, Spring…)?

Comment: I assume `ConnectingText ` is a textview. If so, than you should not update view from background thread

Comment: @hakim and then how should I change the text if it's not from there?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption it is in Android. One option to update UI from a thread is like this.

```
fun connect() {
        val t = Thread(Runnable {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            val str = URL("https://server.necrodragon41.repl.co/server/connect").readText(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
                ConnectingText.post {
                   if (str == "connected") {
                      ConnectingText.text = "Collecting saved data..."
                   } else {
                      ConnectingText.text = "Error connecting."
                  }
                }
        })
        t.start()
    }
```

But I strongly suggest for you to check Kotlin Coroutines or RxJava.
Also, if you happen to be create an Restful API, I suggest to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for API client.